# Database Sync Cloud from MySql to Sqlite Android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization, android-sqlite

I have a remote database that can change at any time. I need to find a way to keep my sqlite database update with all the changes in the better and optimised way possible.

I thought having a single timestamp per table and send only the updated table to the client would be one solution, or maybe having one timestamp per row and sending only the updated row to the client..

But 
- how can i manage deleted items, for example?
- how can i manage the technical update on Android?

Basically, in a few words, at some point in the app, i need to download the changes with an API and update the local db.

Does anyone have some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How much data are we talking here, how many tables and rows in each of these tables?  We talking dozens of rows in each table or millions?

Comment: We're talking about 10-15 tables and hundreds or records, probably up to 200-300..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to follow another approach:

I've created an api that parse the Mysql db into an SQLITE db on the SERVER side. There is a "last_update_timestap" that will be updated every time that something will be changed.

Another api call, gives in the header an extra field containing that timestamp.

On the client side there is a Sync process that do the follow when needed:

1. Api call retrieving just the HEADER, getting the last update timestamp and checking if an update is needed;
2. If is needed download the database from the other api
3. Write the database into a temporary file and copy that temporary file at the position and with the same name of the real database
4. Use the database

Thanks everyone for the help but this turned out to be the suitable approach for my project structure.

Comment: can you show how parse mysql db into sqlite db on server side? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems this is a one-way only sync, I would:

- Make each table on the server DB have a UUID column and a last
  updated date/time column.
- Create a REST call that will request updated data.  Ideally, it would
  take the time the client was updated.  This date should come from the
  server during the update call.
- The server would scan each table searching for rows that have a date > than the date passed.  Serialize the data and return it as JSON along with the server date/time for the next request.

Now tracking deletes is a bit more work.  You can either:

1. Never delete data and only mark the rows as deleted, this is the easiest, but depending on your data may end up with lots of rows in the DB.
2. Delete the data and then track the deleted rows in another table.  These can be deleted after some time and if/when all clients have been updated.
3. Have a second update call that will push down all the UUID values and time stamps for each row.  The client could then figure out which rows need to be deleted.

Though it's the most complex, I'd probably opt for option 3, as I don't like old data hanging around.  The direction I would go would also depend on how  many clients will be syncing with the DB.

Comment: In what kind of json format would you send the update request to the client?

Comment: I'd probably create a POJO that represents each table and a top level object that includes all the tables allowing for multiple rows in each table.  Use Gson or Jackson to marshal the data.